# Is there a way to use weights with both layout width and height

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a layout which has four buttons spread along the bottom of my app using the layout weight to distribute them evenly.

I also want to increase the hight of the buttons using the same sort of weighting.

So far all i can see is either calculating the width with a horizontal linearlayout or height using a vertical linearlayout.

the width is working great its just the height.

If the weight cannot be used at the same time how can i set the height so that it is relative on every screen size.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:weightSum="1.0" 
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/b1"
        android:text="Left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/b2"
        android:text="RotL" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/b3"
        android:text="RotR" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:src="@drawable/b4"
        android:text="Right" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

I dont want to hardcode the heights of the buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Set your `Button`s' heights to `fill_parent`
2. Place your **horizontal** `LinearLayout` in a **vertical** `LinearLayout`
3. Set the **horizontal** `LinearLayout`'s weight <- this is now a vertical weight that will affect your `Button`s' heights

The buttons should resize correctly

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response that worked perfectly! Just for anyone else with this issue to keep the buttons at the bottom the android:gravity="bottom" needs to be moved to the vertical layout. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

Just for adding, you must take into account layout optimization, as said on (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) you should never use nested weights because they are so expensive as each child needs to be measured twice.

In my case i could try GridLayoutInstead, or a RelativeLayout to accomplish the result you want.

Comment: how would you use a relative layout to format buttons based on a percentage of the screens width and hight? Thanks

Comment: Maybe the way to go would be GridLayout, you can see a good example on: http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Comment: I cant see how using a gridLayout will solve my issue of sizing buttons depending on the screen size. This must be a pretty common thing to have buttons displayed in relative sizes depending on the screen size. Could I query the size of the screen and then use variables in the width and height to determine the size. So far i cannot find a suitable solution apart from the one answered above but this effects performance