# Using Relative or GridLayout to evenly distribute buttons depending on screen size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

This is a follow on question from one i have already asked found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824209/is-there-a-way-to-use-weights-with-both-layout-width-and-height)

My question now is how to correctly use a relativelayout or gridlayout to:-

1. Size the buttons with height and width depending on the screen size
2. keep the buttons at the bottom of the view.

Although First question was answered another member JavierSP1209 pointed out that using nested weights is not good for performance. I need to have good performance so i need to do things correctly.

Does any one have any clear methods of how to do this while keeping performance in mind?

Comment: why nested weights? you can use only 1 linear layout for buttons.

Comment: Not to resize both the width and the height depending on screen size. It would appear you would need a nestred linearLayout, one vertical and one horizontal which is bad for performance. How can you do it with just one?

Comment: 1: these weights are in different dimensions, so they don't affect each other and should not cause problems 2: why would you need to stretch the height? this will look strange on many configurations. consider choosing the size (in `dp`)

Comment: because if i have a button thats 80dp on small screen that will look fine, but 80dp on a tablet means the buttons are going to be very small in comparison to the rest of my app. Andriod does throw a warning with the yellow line to say performance will be effected by nested weights.

Comment: on a tablet "stretched up" buttons will look silly, too. chances are that you need different design for tablet

Comment: i have both a very small HTC desire and a samsung Tablet that i am testing with because i use image buttons when sizing like this the image doesnt change just the actual size of the button, later i will add the differnet icon sizes but for now i am not bothered i just want the button size to be bigger on bigger screens